# Are Schwartz class functions analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

We know that $f \in \mathcal{S({\mathbb{R^n}})}$ implies that $f$ has rapidly decreasing derivatives. But does this, by some comparison argument, give us that $f$ is analytic (i.e. equal to its power series expansion)? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Schwartz class function $f$ can be equal to $0$ on a whole interval around $0$, thus its Taylor series at $0$ would be the zero function too, yet $f$ could be non-zero outside of said interval, thus that $f$ can't be analytic (at $0$ at least). You should be able to construct such a $f$ using an adequate bump function I'm sure.

Comment: Any nonzero smooth and compactly supported function is also a counterexample for similar reasons.

Comment: In your example, $f$ is certainly analytic in a neighborhood of the origin (wherein it is identically 0). I guess I should've specified this in my original question, but is it possible for such an $f$ to exist that is not analytic anywhere?

Comment: Hmm it's probably worthy of being posted as another question. I'm not experienced enough to be able to provide an answer to that, though there is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361375/1104384) which might help figuring that out?

Comment: @algebroo Someone found a nowhere analytic Schwartz class function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4641922/1104384), in case you're still interested.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for asking the question! I had a really busy week so I appreciate it.