# The conditions under which the Taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ will converge to $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

**Background**

It is well-known that for the following function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} & \text{if} & x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{if} & x = 0 
\end{cases} $$

the Taylor polynomial does not converge to $f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$, although $f^{(k)}(0)$ exists and it is 0 for all $k\geq 0$. The problem is with the general conditions under which a Taylor polynomial will converge to the function.

**Problem**

In general, what conditions exist (or do they exist at all) such that the Taylor polynomial of a function will converge to the function as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: The $n$-th derivative of **any** polynomial function is another polynomial function and therefore a continuous function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your answer. I understand it now that my question should now change a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such condition is given by [Bernstein's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193121/bernsteins-theorem-of-analytic-function-proof): if $(\forall x\in D_f)(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f^{(n)}(x)\geqslant0$, then the Taylor series of $f$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of every point of $D_f$.