Completely monotone function is analytic
I want to prove the following.
Let $I:=[a,b)$ be finite interval, $f$ is completely monotone on $I$.
Then it can be extended analytically into the complex z-plane
($z=x+iy$), and the function $f(z)$ will be analytic in the circle
$|z-a|<b-a$.
Here is what I started.
By Taylor's
formula for every $a\leq x<b$ we have
\begin{equation*}
 f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k+
 (-1)^{n+1}\int_{a}^x \frac{(-1)^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^{n}dt.
\end{equation*}
Here
\begin{equation*}
R_n(x):=\int_{a}^x \frac{(-1)^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^{n}dt.
\end{equation*}
Since $(-1)^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(t)\geq 0$ and $(-1)^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}$ is monotone decreasing we obtain
\begin{equation*}
0\leq R_n(x)\leq \frac{(-1)^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(a)}{(n+1)!}.
\end{equation*}
I don't know how to finish the proof, assuming that it can be finished at all.

Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193121/42969 to me. Note that $x \mapsto f(-x)$ has all derivatives nonnegative.

This is called “little Bernshtein theorem” in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_and_completely_monotonic_functions_and_sequences

@MartinR Before posting the question I read a lot of paper, books, and everywhere was used $g(x):=f(-x)$, but my idea was to prove the statement without this. But no problem, this trick makes the proof simpler. Thanks for the reference, I couldn't find it because there is no completely-monotone keywords, I tried to use, but SAAD deleted it. That post is nice, but not gives the desired radius of convergence; hopefully I can do with a very little modification of some published proofs. Thanks for your help.
